# Deep Dream: CPU works but not GPU, Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am very new to this, so apologies if my terminology isn't perfect, but I've done a lot of trying and searching but I cant get passed this issue.

I have been trying to create Deep dream style transferred images so I can batch process them for video.

I have tried a whole bunch of different things and guides and versions, i could not get tensorflow to install on python 3.6.6 or newer.
But following this guide:

(https://www.reddit.com/r/deepdream/comments/6z5tyz/guide_on_how_to_setup_neural_style_transfer_on/)

I finally got it to work but only as tensor flow CPU. this is great but very slow I have a GTX 1080 and I want to make the most of that.

when I install Tensorflow-gpu, it says its worked fine

```
C:\Users\kurti>pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/01/ac/ed64953d36b6516dc4a4ae983d7759bdcdaedd65541ee92a116909a524a8/tensorflow_gpu-1.13.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: gast>=0.2.0 in c:\users\kurti\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already up-to-date: keras-applications>=1.0.6 in c:\users\kurti\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already up-to-date: keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 in c:\users\kurti\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already up-to-date: absl-py>=0.1.6 in c:\users\kurti\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already up-to-date: protobuf>=3.6.1 in c:\users\kurti\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already up-to-date: termcolor>=1.1.0 in c:\users\kurti\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already up-to-date: wheel>=0.26 in c:\users\kurti\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already up-to-date: astor>=0.6.0 in c:\users\kurti\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already up-to-date: tensorflow-estimator<1.14.0rc0,>=1.13.0 in c:\users\kurti\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\kurti\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.10.0 in c:\users\kurti\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already up-to-date: grpcio>=1.8.6 in c:\users\kurti\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already up-to-date: tensorboard<1.14.0,>=1.13.0 in c:\users\kurti\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already up-to-date: h5py in c:\users\kurti\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from keras-applications>=1.0.6->tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in c:\users\kurti\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from protobuf>=3.6.1->tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already up-to-date: mock>=2.0.0 in c:\users\kurti\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-estimator<1.14.0rc0,>=1.13.0->tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already up-to-date: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in c:\users\kurti\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<1.14.0,>=1.13.0->tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already up-to-date: markdown>=2.6.8 in c:\users\kurti\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<1.14.0,>=1.13.0->tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already up-to-date: pbr>=0.11 in c:\users\kurti\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from mock>=2.0.0->tensorflow-estimator<1.14.0rc0,>=1.13.0->tensorflow-gpu)
Installing collected packages: tensorflow-gpu
Successfully installed tensorflow-gpu-1.13.1
```

but when I test by importing the GPU version I get this:

```
C:\Users\kurti>python
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kurti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\kurti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\kurti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\kurti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\kurti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\kurti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\kurti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\kurti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kurti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\kurti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\kurti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\kurti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\kurti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

The fact the CPU works suggests to me its something to do with either the versions of CUDA, cuDNN or the version of Tensor flow GPU but i have tried

```
Cuda 8(update2) + CuDNN 6
Cuda 8(update2) + CuDNN 5.1
Cuda 7.5 + cuDNN 5.1
```

plus a whole bunch of newer ones before.
I believe i have all the correct dependencies installed.

I have checked the PATH, as other people with similar problems on here have suggested and that seems all fine so i have no idea where to go from here?

I have this working for CPU but I need to be able to do hundreds of these for video, so any help would be hugely appreciated thanks.

---

***UPDATE:*** I found this nice little Self check script for versions prior to 1.4 [link](https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c)

this said that it could not find cuDNN v6 which i installed, then tested, still same error. ran self check again and got this result

```
C:\Users\kurti\Documents\Projects SSD\TESTS\Deep Dream>tensorflow_self_check.py
ERROR: Failed to import the TensorFlow module.

WARNING! This script is no longer maintained!
=============================================

Since TensorFlow 1.4, the self-check has been integrated with TensorFlow itself,
and any missing DLLs will be reported when you execute the `import tensorflow`
statement. The error messages printed below refer to TensorFlow 1.3 and earlier,
and are inaccurate for later versions of TensorFlow.

- Python version is 3.5.

- TensorFlow is installed at: C:\Users\kurti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow

- All required DLLs appear to be present. Please open an issue on the
  TensorFlow GitHub page: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues
```

***UPDATE 2:***

After some more research it was advised to use Anaconda as this apparently is less prone to issues, such as the one above, in windows.
these are the steps i am taking

1. conda create -n [name] python=3.5
2. activate [name]
3. conda install tensorflow-gpu
4. pip3 install (numpy-1.16.2+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl)
5. pip3 install (opencv_python-3.4.5-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl)
6. pip3 install (scipy-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl)

this gives me no errors when i then type

```
python
>>>import tensorflow
>>>import numpy
```

but when i try and run the script (which was working for cpu version) it can no longer find numpy

```
    (tf2) C:\Users\kurti\GitProjects\DeepStyle\Deep Style\neural-style-tf-master>neural_style.py --content_img littleme.jpg --style_imgs starry-night.jpg --max_iterations 100 --verbose
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kurti\GitProjects\DeepStyle\Deep Style\neural-style-tf-master\neural_style.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\kurti\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\kurti\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

running pip3 list shows numpy,
running pip list shows numpy,
running conda list shows the wrong numpy,

i believe running the pip3 install for the required .whl's is not installing them to my conda enviroment could this be correct and how do i solve that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is helpful, but the Tensorflow installation docs suggest that the Windows GPU version will only work with `cuDNN64_7.dll`, so I'm guessing that's cuDNN v6? I only mention this as the error looks like it can't find the required `.dll`, maybe it's the cuDNN one? There is some extra info in the docs about how to set paths etc., let me know how you go.

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#windows_setup

Comment: Hey thanks for that, I didnt have `cuDNN64_7.dll`, but even with that now i still get the same error,
I tried `Cuda v8 + cuDNN v7.3
cuda v9 + cuDNN v7.3`  ( `cuDNN v7.3` wast the _7 one)
still get exactly the same error
I have double checked the %PATH% and at the end of the echo %PATH% all the ones from your link are there 

 i went to this location (from the first part of the error `"C:\Users\kurti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py"`,  and that file does exist, so once again im lost